# Use formula field on command

Tags: crystal-reports

I added my query as a command. Now I want that flexibility on the date section. I'd like to retrieve a value from the formula field like below:

```
select field1, field2, field3,
  case 
    when flag = 0 and yes_date = {@the_date} 
      then 'ok'
    when flag > 0  
      then 'not_ok'    
  end as currentsts   
from trans
```

The formula field `@the_date` is being populated by the application before calling the report. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use a formula in a Command Query. You can only have a command parameter that you create from Database Expert. The command parameter would look like:

`yes_date = {?the_date}`

When you run the report with a command parameter, you can have a suggested default value or enter a value in manually. This value then becomes part of your query, typically somewhere in your where clause.

[image]

Comment: it needs to be a value passed from the application.  no workarounds?

Comment: I don't know of a way to pass parameters on the SQL level without inputting it manually. There are many tech articles online on how to use create a parameter (not command parameter) where a default value can be used... but you must return all the result set then filter it afterwards not before hand.

Answer (score 0):

You could try selecting the formula into a temporary variable at the beginning of your command query:
`DECLARE @The_Date AS DATE = (SELECT ISNULL(t2.date,t1.date) FROM table1 AS t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table 2 AS t2 ON t2.pk = t1.pk WHERE whatever = '{?parameter}');`
But this will have to return a single value. Otherwise, you'll have to put your command query into a subreport and pass your formula as the parameter in the subreport links.